# How do I make a foreign key that can be two different data types without using CREATE CAST?

Tags: postgresql, heroku-postgres

I have two types of tables: Tables with a UUID primary key and tables with a BIGINT primary key.

I have a specific table that references tables with *either type* of primary key.

I cannot use `CREATE CAST (character varying AS uuid) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT` because I do not own `character varying` or `uuid` (heroku).

Assume for example's sake these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.changelogs (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    record_type character varying NOT NULL,
    -- record_id ??? NOT NULL,
    event character varying NOT NULL,
    actor_id uuid,
    transitions jsonb,
    object_changes jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    group_id text NOT NULL
);
```

And these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.recipes (
    id uuid DEFAULT public.gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL,
    slug public.citext NOT NULL,
    moderation_state public.citext NOT NULL,
    description text NOT NULL,
    author_id uuid NOT NULL,
    ingredients text[] DEFAULT '{}'::text[] NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    instructions character varying[] DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[] NOT NULL,
    cook_time integer NOT NULL,
    prep_time integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.allergies (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: `I have a specific table that references tables with either type of primary key.` that seems like a provably empty table, please give an example of what you would like to do,

Comment: @Jasen It's a table of changes to records, how's that?

Comment: And what are the references relationships you want to define?

Comment: I don't understand your question @Jasen, I want to have foreign keys that point other tables, but those tables have different primary key types.

Comment: what you seem to describe is impossible even if all the keys are the same type.

Comment: You'd need one column (of the correct type) for each table you'd want to reference, then perhaps a CHECK constraint so that exactly one of those columns would be non-NULL.

Comment: @muistooshort That's an interesting solution.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That isn't even remotely similar a question. All 3 table have the same primary key type. Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes I did. And the answer solves your requirement: "*I have a specific table that references tables with either type of primary key*" - create one column for each reference and a check constraint that makes sure that only one of them is specified. Exactly what the answer in that question shows (except that the two columns happen to use the same data types, but the pattern used there doesn't require that)

Comment: The duplicate's answer suggests the same thing I suggested: one column for each table that needs to be referenced and a CHECK constraint to make sure exactly one of them is non-NULL. You can't make one column do two things in any sane fashion.